# Downloading a file generated by a HTTP post using JAVA APACHE HTTPClient

Tags: java, apache, post, download, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have a need to log into a webpage, download a file (that appears after a post) and then log out again.

Logging in and out is fine, but I am having some troubles when I try to get to the file.

In a web browser I fill in the form once I press OK it does to a webpage saying 'Successful' and a file download box appears.

When I do the same thing via HTTP client (copying the parameters used in FF by firebug) all I get the the response.entity is the webpage, but I cannot see the file anywhere. Can someone please shed some light on my problem?

Here is my code (I realize it will not at the moment save the response, but if it was working, I would expect some long binary response)

```
// get data
httpost = new HttpPost("https://webpage.com.au/folder/getfile.asp?param=2");
List <NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList <NameValuePair>();
nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("p1", "0"));
nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("p2", "03"));
nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("p3", "1"));
nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("p4", "6"));
nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("p5", "1"));
nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("p6", "2"));
nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("p7", "1"));
nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("p8", "0"));
nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("p9", "G"));

httpost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps, Consts.UTF_8));   
response = httpclient.execute(httpost);
entity = response.getEntity();
printResponse(entity);

System.out.println("Get file post: " + response.getStatusLine());
EntityUtils.consume(entity);

System.out.println("Post file get cookies:");
printCookies(httpclient);
```

and the response:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"> 
<head>
<title></title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<meta name="language" content="en-us"/>
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow"/>
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache"/>
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css" type="text/css"/>
<script language="javascript">
    var wasSubmitted = false;

    function SingleSubmit () 
    { 
        var OK = !wasSubmitted; 
        wasSubmitted = true; 
        return OK;
    }
</script>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" text="black" topmargin="0" leftmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
<br>
<center><br><p class="center"></p><p class="center"></p><p class="center">getting file<br>
  <script language=Javascript>
      document.location = "TransSumExcel.asp";
  </script>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the response text it appears that the browser is directed to load 'TransSumExcel.asp' by the javascript call

```
 document.location = "TransSumExcel.asp";
```

So right after the POST request you need to make a GET request for https://webpage.com.au/folder/TransSumExcel.asp

Comment: @manverdra Thanks for that! It was almost a perfect answer and showed my lack of JS skills! Unfortunately, it didn't work completely...I now get a downloaded file, but it is empty apart from the CSV headers. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Try [Fiddler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250446(v=vs.85).aspx). You can examine the communication between your browser and web server and see exactly what is posted (all request parameters and the cookies).   
  
Some web applications check the referrer header and if it does not match what they are expecting, they can reject the request and send back empty response.   

Using Fiddler you can see the exact request and if you mimic same using HTTP client you should be able to get it working